# Display columns that are from three different tables that don't exist in a fourth table

Tags: sql

```
TableDates
================
- mDate

tblLocations
================
- location_id
- location

tblSignature_labels
===================
- signature_label_id
- signature_label
- isrequired bit

tblsignatures
====================
- location_id
- signature_label_id
- signature_date
```

I need to display the date, location and signature_label that don't exist in the `tblsignatures` table where `tblsignatures.signature_date = tblDates.mdate` and the `tblSignature_labels.isrequired=1` and the `tblLocations.location_id=tblSignatures.location_id`

So if one of the signature_labels isrequired and the `location_id` and the date for that location are not in the signatures table, list the date, location and the signature label that's not in the signatures table... Clear as mud right?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate all combinations of the first three tables.  Then some more logic (such as `left join`) to exclude the ones that are populated:

```
select d.mdate, l.location_id, sl.signature_label
from tableDates d cross join
     tblLocations l cross join
     tblSignature_labels sl left join
     tblsignatures s
     on s.location_id = l.location_id and
        s.signature_label_id = sl.signature_label_id and
        s.signature_date = d.mDate
where s.location_id is null;
```